# Why does $\sigma (X_t) \subset \sigma (X)$ hold?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

We have a random process $X=\{X_t\;,t\in T\}$, where $X_t:(\Omega,\mathcal{A})\to(S_t,\mathcal{S}_t)$ are random variables. I am confused as to why does
$$\sigma (X_t) \subset \sigma (X)$$
hold $\forall t\in T$.

**More background**:  Intuitively, this makes sense, rigorously, I am at loss. I suspect this might have something to do with my poor understanding of $\sigma(\text{anything})$ (perhaps later spawning a subsequent question), however, this is my thinking so far:

$\sigma(X_t)=\{[X_t\in B_t],B_t\in \mathcal{S}_t\}$ and 
$\sigma(X)=\{[X\in B],B\in \mathcal{S}\}$ where $\mathcal{S}=\bigotimes S_t$ (the product $\sigma$-algebra, i.e. the smallest $\sigma$-algebra on $\prod S_t$ containg measurable cylinders)

Now, perhaps I could write $[X\in B]=[\{X_t\}\in B]$ and perhaps somehow $B=\prod B_t$, and so maybe $[X\in B]$ really equals to something like $\bigcap[ X_t\in B_t]$ which looks much more like what I want, but a) this is almost just wishful thinking with my poor understanding of the topic and b) even then I am not sure how to proceed.

Hope this makes sense (doesn't to me so far!) and thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, $\sigma(X_t)$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F} \subseteq \mathcal{A}$ such that $X_t:(\Omega,\mathcal{F}) \to (S_t,\mathcal{S}_t)$ is measurable. Therefore, it suffices to show that $X_t$ is measurable with respect to $\sigma(X)$. To this end, we associate to $B_t \in \mathcal{S}_t$ the cylinder set

$$B := \{(s_r)_{r \in T} \in \prod_{r \in T} S_r; s_t \in B_t\}.$$

It follows from the very definition of $\sigma(X)$ and $B$ that

$$\begin{align*} X_t^{-1}(B_t)  &= X^{-1}(B) \in \sigma(X). \end{align*}$$

This already proves that $X_t$ is measurable with respect to $\sigma(X)$.

---

Answers to your questions:

1. Measurable as a mapping $X_t: (\Omega,\mathcal{F}) \to (S_t,\mathcal{S}_t)$, i.e. $X_t^{-1}(A) \in \mathcal{F}$ for all $A \in \mathcal{S}_t$.
2. If $X_t$ is measurable with respect to $\sigma(X)$, i.e. $X_t: (\Omega,\sigma(X)) \to (S_t,\mathcal{S}_t)$ is measurable, then $\sigma(X_t) \subseteq \sigma(X)$ since $\sigma(X_t)$ is the *smallest* $\sigma$-algebra such that $X_t$ is measurable (in the sense of 1.).
3. $(s_r)_{r \in T}$ is simply an element of the product space $\prod_{r \in T} S_r$, i.e. for each $r \in T$, we have $s_r \in S_r$.

Comment: Thanks, this answer is still quite cryptic to me though. A couple of questions: **a)** $X_t$ is measurable in what sense? $\forall B\in\mathcal{S}_t$ we have $X^{-1}_t\in\sigma(X)$? **b)** Could you please elaborate on "it suffices to show.."? (It mostly confuses me as in the definition  or $\sigma(X)$ we consider $\mathcal{S}$ as opposed to $\mathcal{S}_t$). **c)** What does the notation $(s_r)_{r \in T} $ mean? Sorry for being kinda slow, I have poor background in measure theory (working on that..)

Comment: @DahnJahn I have just edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks, answers cleared my questions up, sadly, I still need a (hopefully) small nudge. Measurable cylinders are where most of my problems with probability theory mostly occur. **a)** do we agree on the definition that $B_t=S_t$ except for finitely many $t$'s? If so then is $B$ such a set? and finally **b)** Why does $X_t^{-1}(B) = X^{-1}(B)$? I am not even sure what $X_t^{-1}(B)$ means - since B seems to be a collection of elements of $\prod S_t$.

Comment: @DahnJahn a) What do you mean by $B_t = S_t$ for finitely many $t$? We have *fixed* $t$ and a set $B_t \in S_t$. Now $B$ consists all elements of $(s_r)_{r \in T} \prod_{r \in T} S_r$ such that for this (fixed!) $t$, $s_t \in B_t$. b) $X_t^{-1}(B_t) = \{\omega \in \Omega; X_t(\omega) \in B_t\}$. (Sorry, there was a typo; it should read $X_t^{-1}(B_t)$ instead of $X_t^{-1}(B)$.)

Comment: I meant the definition of a (measurable) cylinder. I still don't see why $X_t^{-1}(B_t)=X^{-1}(B)$. Please comment a bit more on that.

Comment: @DahnJahn Can't write much on that; it's really the definition of preimages and $B$: $$\begin{align*} X_t^{-1}(B_t) &= \{\omega \in \Omega; X_t(\omega) \in B_t\} \\ &= \{\omega \in \Omega; X_t(\omega) \in B_t, \forall r \neq t: X_r(\omega) \in S_r\} \\ &= X^{-1}(B). \end{align*}$$